# bootstrap 5 collapse in foreach | how to set only first element with shown

Tags: php, bootstrap-5

```
<?php foreach ($offers as $item): ?>
<h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading<?php echo $item->id; ?>"></h2>
<div id="collapse<?php echo $item->id; ?>" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $item->id; ?>" data-bs-parent="#default-accordion-example">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
<?php echo $item->id; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

This give me result:  example 10 collapse tabs with content: `1,5,6,8,10,15,20....`

issue: all collapse is opened.

I know the problem is loop:

```
class="accordion-collapse collapse show"
```

But how to resolve and make first tab show and rest close in foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show` should only be on the first element you want opened. The easiest way to keep track is to use the key, if the array doesn't have custom keys, or an iterator. Use a ternary to check for that first key, and only echo `show` if it's the first key.

```
<?php foreach ($offers as $key => $item): ?>
<h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading<?php echo $item->id; ?>"></h2>
<div id="collapse<?php echo $item->id; ?>" class="accordion-collapse collapse <?php echo $key == 0 ? 'show' : '' ?>" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $item->id; ?>" data-bs-parent="#default-accordion-example">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
<?php echo $item->id; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```